# Unable to load html5 mp3 audio with quarkus

Tags: quarkus, quake2

I am working on j2cl port of gwt quake2, at this moment all works ok  (work still in progress) with wildfly, but not with quarkus.

The problem is: any requests to mp3 files are left in a pending state, all other files are loading correctly.

```
<audio preload="auto"><source src="baseq2/sound/misc/menu1.wav.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

with wildfly all works ok.

To be honest i have no idea what is wrong, looks like i'm missing something.

How to reproduce:

Pre-requisites:

- java 1.8 (java.nio emulation atm works only with java 1.8, otherwise there're errors like :  error: package exists in another module: java.base)
- maven 3.6
- quarkus 1.5.1
- tested on linux

  clone https://github.com/treblereel/quake2-gwt-port 
  run com.googlecode.gwtquake.tools.Installer from the server module (it ll download and convert resources to war folder)

For wildfly:

1) copy baseq2 from war dir to server/src/main/webapp/ 
2) run mvn clean package 
3) deploy to wildfly 
4) open http://127.0.0.1:8080/quake2/ and check all good

For quarkus:

1) checkout quarkus branch 
2) copy baseq2 from war dir to server/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/
3) run mvn clean package
4) java -jar server/target/quake2-runner.jar
5) open http://0.0.0.0:8080/quake2/
6) check that menu1.wav.mp3 is on pending state forever.

Any ideas ? thanks for help.

Comment: I followed the steps above and it works in my browser. Had to install `lame` and `vorbis-tools` before running the installer though (with `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.googlecode.gwtquake.tools.Installer` in the `server` project)

Running on Fedora 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a quarkus 1.5.2 issue, probably ll be fixed in 1.6.0. The workaround is to override io.quarkus.http deps to 3.0.11.Final. In my case quarkus-http-vertx-backend, quarkus-http-core, quarkus-http-servlet and quarkus-http-websockets-jsr. After all it works great.